# Can't see all the posts I've published

Tags: blogger

Please I need your help

In my Blogspot I've posted 11 posts and my blog shows up 6 on the main page but the problem in the second page I can't see the other posts only 3 and every time I post another post, at the main page I can't have 6posts I start seeing only 5 posts

Here is my Blogspot: https://sth-deco.blogspot.com/

Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 2):

This problem has nothing to do with blogger but the problem is in the theme/template that work like this to really solve your problem you need to contact your [template maker](https://www.soratemplates.com/) and i hope they will fix your problem